# What's inheritance by value and inheritance by reference?

Tags: c#, c++, c

Someone just asked me this question, but I am a C# programmer and I only knows about class inheritance.... I wonder is this thing only for C/C++?  Is inheritance by reference means we create a ClassA then ClassB inherted from this ClassA? Actually what are they?

=====
Edit to make it clear:

Here is the question context my friend got and he was doing a C programming test:

```
"There are two types of inheritance: inheritance by value and inheritance by reference. Show how to design a class to implement inheritance by reference"
```

So I am assuming, that should be related to C/C++...But I never heard of inheritance by value and inheritance by reference.  But like Bn said in the post, I only heard of pass by value and pass by reference... Or maybe I am wrong?  Because I am a C# programmer, so I don't really know about C/C++ stuff...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean structural and nominal subtyping?

Comment: Inheritance is only related to acquiring behaviors and properties from a parent class.  The concepts of 'value' and 'reference' do not apply here.

Comment: There's a major terminological mix-up going on in that question. I don't know whether the author of the question is responsible for it, or your friend just quoted it incorrectly. But in its current form the question just doesn't make much sense. I can force myself to invent some more-or-less logical interpretation for these combinations of terms, but I'm afraid it will prove to be a waste of time when we discover that the question is simply misquoted.

Comment: I think you are right I guess I will wait for his test to come back or after he ask the teacher :) I am asking this question is just really doubt if I am just missing some knowledge.

Comment: I think maybe the question refers to the different ways to **implement** inheritance. I teach a class where I make the students implement object-oriented concepts in C, so that they understand what is going on under the hood; perhaps this is the same here. In this case, "inheritance by value" and "by reference" could refer to the way you link derived classes to base classes, either by embedding the base object into the derived object, or by storing a pointer to the base object (which is useful for implementing virtual inheritance).

Comment: I'm already very suspicious when a **C** test mentions inheritance. Just to clarify to C# programmers: C and C++ are quite distinct languages. For instance, C++ has explicit support in the language for inheritance, while C doesn't. That makes "C/C++" a misnomer; even "C#/C++" makes more sense. At least those two share OO notions like `public/protected/private`.

Answer (score 5):

I have not heard of this term in relation to C or C++.  Do you possibly have one of the two concept in mind?

1. Pass by reference and pass by value.
2. Implementation inheritance and interface inheritance.

Perhaps a further example would help lead to a definition, or the source where you heard the terms used would be helpful.

Comment: I do know about both the concept. But I just never heard of the stuff I ask before lol.  My friend got that quetion in test as follows: "There are two types of inheritance: inheritance by value and inheritance by reference. Show how to design a class to implement inheritance by reference"

Comment: Perhaps he meant class inheritance via implementation inheritance vs. inheritance of an interface using composition?

Comment: hmmm maybe you are right.  I will have to see what he said after he ask the teacher. :)

Comment: @bn: `inheritance of an interface using composition?` Inheritance using Compostion is not possible, Inheritance is a `is a` relationship, Composition is a `has a` relationship, both are distinctly different.

Comment: @Als You are correct my statement is not as clear as it could have been.  Although you can accomplish the "is a" and "has a" relationships with composition or inheritance.  But this can be a huge debate sometimes based on differences in language terminology (for example, not having an interface keyword in C+++ doesn't mean you can't have interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree that the question is poorly worded (unless there is context not provided in the original post). Having said that, it's possible the question refers to virtual and non-virtual inheritance.

[Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) in C++ is useful due to the languages support for multiple inheritance (and the various issues that arise) See the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) for a good explanation of this topic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This could (awkardly) fit: when using virtual inheritance, the base class object is not contained in the derived class objects, but referenced with a pointer, so this could be what "inheritance by reference" refers to...